# Flutter add bottom margin to Stack

Tags: flutter

I am trying to extend Stack a little bit down to create room for "All caught up" text.

Here is my code;

```
  return Stack(
        children: [
          buildListView(scrollController),
          buildBackToTop(scrollController, backtoTop),
          buildBottomReached(isLastIndex),
        ],
      );
```

```
Widget buildBackToTop(ScrollController scrollController, bool backtoTop) {
  if (backtoTop) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: () {
            scrollController.animateTo(0,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                curve: Curves.linear);
          },
          label: const Text("Back to Top"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } else {
    return const SizedBox();
  }
}
```

```
Widget buildBottomReached(bool isLastIndex) {
  if (isLastIndex) {
    return const Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Text(
        "All caught up ",
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.blue, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.00),
      ),
    );
  } else {
    return const SizedBox();
  }
}
```

```
Widget buildListView(ScrollController scrollController) {
  return ListView.builder(
      controller: scrollController,
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 20,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                color: Colors.grey[100],
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text("Index $index"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics());
}
```

[image]

When I do following,

```
  return Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),
          child: buildListView(scrollController),
        ),
        buildBackToTop(scrollController, backtoTop),
        buildBottomReached(isLastIndex),
      ],
    );
```

This is desired but it adds whitespace to bottom all the time,

[image]
[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try to wrap with `Positioned` widget?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your UI. try `Column` widget instead of `Stack`.

```dart
  return Column(
        children: [
          Expaneded(child: buildListView(scrollController)),
          buildBackToTop(scrollController, backtoTop),
          buildBottomReached(isLastIndex),
        ],
      );
```

If it needs overlay, use Stack by combining listView and Text with Column.

Wrap the widget with `Positioned` and add `bottom`.

```dart
 return Stack(
        children: [
         .....
         Positioned(
           bottom: yourValue,
           child:
```

Comment: This one positions elements on the Stack, it does not extend the Stack. So if I use this Text overlays on the last element of the ListViewItem where I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Try to provide `top:0,left:0,right:0,bottom:8` .I might be mistaken, are you trying to change the position of  `"All caught up"`, or have some padding around it?

Comment: I want "All caught up" to be under the ListView actually. So it should not overlay with it. So what I was thinking to extend stack but IDK if that's possible.

Comment: ok For ListView, use `Positined.fill(child:`

Comment: ^^ this made ListView to disappear from screen. Probably I am missing something.

Comment: Can you provide full sample widget from scaffold body?

Comment: One more thing, you can have `padding` on ListView if it is just for end case

Comment: I added more context. My full code has lots of other crap so it is hard to extract, but basically it is `MaterialView -> Scaffold -> body -> Stack`. I tried padding but it cuts-off screen from the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for collaboration.  Do you like to have space always for `All caught up`? It would be easier for me if can include a desire output image.

Comment: Thanks, I included in the question. Please see the bottom part of the question.

Comment: I think you want Column widget instead of Stack

Comment: I cannot place ListView under Column :(

Comment: You need to wrap `ListView` with `Expanded` widget

Answer (score 0):

another valid solution for your case is to expand the `Stack` to the screen size, then align your widgets with the `Align` widget like this:

```
final mq = MediaQuery.of(context);
return ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight: mq.size.height,
    minHeight: mq.size.height,
    maxWidth: mq.size.width,
    minWidth: mq.size.width,
  ),
  child: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      buildListView(scrollController),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: buildBackToTop(scrollController, backtoTop),
      ),
      buildBottomReached(isLastIndex),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this renders same exact thing of what I have.

Answer (score 0):

First, wrap `Stack` with `ListView` widget

Then, move `buildBottomReached` helper as a sibling of the `Stack` widget

```
return ListView(//this
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            buildListView(),
            buildBackToTop(backtoTop),
            //buildBottomReached(isLastIndex),//move this a sibling of the Stack
          ],
        ),
        buildBottomReached(isLastIndex),//moved here
      ],
    );
```

Then, on `buildListView` helper, set `ListView.builder` property `shrinkWrap` to `true`.

```
Widget buildListView(ScrollController scrollController) {
  return ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,//this
      controller: scrollController,
      itemCount: 50,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: 20,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 20,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                color: Colors.grey[100],
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text("Index $index"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics());
}
```